# Install PECL extension and enable PHP ZTS on cloudControl

Tags: php, pecl, buildpack, cloudcontrol

How do I install a PECL extension for PHP on the [cloudControl](https://www.cloudcontrol.com/) platform?

Do i need to create a custom [Buildpack](https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Platform%20Documentation#buildpacks-and-the-procfile)?

**EDIT:** I tried to install the extension following [this tutorial](http://www.amido.co.uk/chris-gray/compiling-php-extensions-like-mongo-and-memcache-on-heroku/). My commands:

```
cctrlapp APP_NAME/DEP_NAME run bash
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/pthreads-0.0.45.tgz
tar -xvzf pthreads-0.0.45.tgz
cd pthreads-0.0.45
/usr/bin/phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config
```

But then I got the message "error: pthreads requires ZTS, please re-compile PHP with ZTS enabled"

Is it possible to enable ZTS on the cloudControl platform?

Comment: is there anything you tried?

Comment: No. The only way I see, is to build a custom buildpack, but I don't know exactly how. I thought there might be an easier way to do this.

Comment: The PHP buildpack uses php-fpm and does not run PHP as an Apache module. I'm no expert but it seems this is what ZTS is related to. So in that case, a custom buildpack is your only option afaik. On the other hand, there might be some on Github already.